# Получить местоположение

Tags: java, android

Как получить местоположение устройства и вывести в TextView ширину и долготу?

Comment: [Урок 138. Определение местоположения.](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/291-urok-138-opredelenie-mestopolozhenija-gps-koordinaty.html)